# PCIe bus error: severity=uncorrected for ubuntu NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04, network-manager

I am trying to connect to wifi in ubuntu then suddenly the wifi adapter stops (ubuntu setting shows no wifi option). When I checked system logs using `journalctl -ef` I get the following output:

```bash
Jun 15 13:58:10 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:   device [8086:06b5] error status/mask=00200000/00010000
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: unmasked uncorrectable error detected
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: containment event, status:0x1f01 source:0x0000
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: device recovery failed
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: subordinate device reset failed
Jun 15 13:58:09 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: Data Link Layer Link Active not set in 1000 msec
Jun 15 13:58:08 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:   device [8086:06b5] error status/mask=00200000/00010000
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: unmasked uncorrectable error detected
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: containment event, status:0x1f01 source:0x0000
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: device recovery failed
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: subordinate device reset failed
Jun 15 13:58:07 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: Data Link Layer Link Active not set in 1000 msec
Jun 15 13:58:06 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jun 15 13:58:05 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
Jun 15 13:58:05 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Jun 15 13:58:05 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
Jun 15 13:58:05 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:   device [8086:06b5] error status/mask=00200000/00010000
Jun 15 13:58:05 fishnak-ASUS-TUF kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

This error has been happening for sometime now and mostly fixes by a  reboot. But currently the frequency of this error gets increasing day by day. I am sharing some other info related to hardware:

```bash
❯ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: ec:2e:98:ef:96:41
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:141 memory:c2100000-c21fffff memory:c2200000-c2203fff memory:c2204000-c2204fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: 7c:10:c9:90:27:c8
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c5204000-c5204fff memory:c5200000-c5203fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

NetworkManager logs: (using `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service`)

```bash
Jun 15 13:54:18 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817458.1911] device (wlx503eaaaed109): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Jun 15 13:54:18 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817458.2330] device (wlx503eaaaed109): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jun 15 13:54:19 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817459.2278] device (wlx503eaaaed109): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jun 15 13:54:19 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817459.2385] device (wlx503eaaaed109): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jun 15 13:54:19 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817459.2385] device (wlx503eaaaed109): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "partha"
Jun 15 13:54:19 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817459.2386] device (wlx503eaaaed109): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 15 13:54:19 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817459.2392] dhcp4 (wlx503eaaaed109): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.6717] dhcp4 (wlx503eaaaed109): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.44
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.6762] device (wlx503eaaaed109): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.7208] device (wlx503eaaaed109): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.7210] device (wlx503eaaaed109): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.7213] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817462.7230] device (wlx503eaaaed109): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 15 13:54:22 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <warn>  [1686817462.7267] dns-sd-resolved[bc42b9b3d4a8e758]: send-updates SetLinkDomains@6 failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 6 not known
Jun 15 13:54:32 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817472.9868] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 15 13:54:32 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817472.9869] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 15 13:54:32 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817472.9869] policy: set 'partha 1' (wlx503eaaaed109) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 15 13:55:16 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817516.3067] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 15 13:55:16 fishnak-ASUS-TUF NetworkManager[8866]: <info>  [1686817516.3077] policy: set 'gpd0' (gpd0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
```

Please help me diagnose the error, and how to fix it. The wifi had worked properly for a some months before this error had occured.If I use a spare USB wifi adapter from my home, the wifi runs properly.